# Adding time and date stamp to exported file

Tags: powershell, date, time

I have the below script which i am working on. However I can not seem to get a date/time stamp for the excel file that is output. Ideally I would like to run this script a few times and each time save a different file name in date/time order.

At the moment it only saves as the one file and gets rewritten over after each run.

Multiple Computers, Servers search code:

```
$Output = @()
$computername = "COMPUTERNAME" #Put name of computer(s) and or Server(S)
ForEach($Computer in $computername)
{
    $events = Get-WinEvent -Computername $Computer -FilterHashtable @{
        LogName = "application"
        Level = 2   #1 Critical, 2 Error , 3 Warning, 4 Information
    }
    ForEach($event in $events)
    {
        $output += $event | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'computername' -NotePropertyValue $Computer -PassThru
    }
}
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$CurrentDatev= $CurrentDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy---hh-mm-ss") + ".csv"
$Output | Export-Csv C:\adamtest100.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change last two lines of your code -

```
$CurrentDatev = $CurrentDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy---hh-mm-ss")
$Output | Export-Csv C:\adamtest100_$($CurrentDatev).csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Cheers Vivek :)